# Java Properties Class

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

using java 8, tomcat 8

Hi, i am loading a file using properties, but i have a check before loading which returns the same properties object if its already been loaded (not null). which is a normal case scenario but i want to know if there is any way that if any change occur in target file, and some trigger should be called and refreshes all the properties objects. here is my code.

```
public static String loadConnectionFile(String keyname) {
              String message = "";

              getMessageFromConnectionFile();
               if (propertiesForConnection.containsKey(keyname))
                message = propertiesForConnection.getProperty(keyname);

               return message;
            }

public static synchronized void getMessageFromConnectionFile() {
              if (propertiesForConnection == null) {
               FileInputStream fileInput = null;
               try {
                File file = new File(Constants.GET_CONNECTION_FILE_PATH);
                fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput, "UTF-8");
                propertiesForConnection = new Properties();
                propertiesForConnection.load(reader);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                Utilities.printErrorLog(Utilities.convertStackTraceToString(e), logger);
               } finally {
                try {
                 fileInput.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                 Utilities.printErrorLog(Utilities.convertStackTraceToString(e), logger);
                }
               }
              }
             }
```

the loadConnectionFile method executes first and calls getMessageFromConnectionFile which has check implemented for "null", now if we remove that check it will definitely load updated file every time but it will slower the performance. i want an alternate way.

hope i explained my question.
thanks in advance.

Comment: "now if we remove that check it will definitely load updated file every time" - no, it will load it once. After that, `propertiesForConnection` won't be null, so it won't load it the next time.

Comment: that's why i mentioned, "if we remove that check"

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - sorry, not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Java has a file watcher service. It is an API. You can "listen" for changes in files and directories. So you can listen for changes to your properties file, or the directory in which your properties file is located. The *Java Tutorials* on Oracle's OTN Web site has a [section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) on the watcher service.

Good Luck,

Avi.

Comment: Hi Avi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer as answers which just contain links to Oracle tutorials are not much use.